# Installing an insignia connect smart switch to three black wires and a bundle of three white wires

Tags: switch, light

I have the configuration coming to my new smart switch. The smart switch requires a line wire, load wire, and neutral wire. I originally connected my manual light switch as seen in the picture, but when I tried this set up with my smart switch, nothing happens. First question: what is the group of three white wires capped together? Second: would the group of two black (mind the white stuff) wires capped together coming from my wall be the neutral and the single black wire the line wire?

On the smart switch the black is the line, blue is the load, white is the neutral, and green is the ground (which i do not have).

[image: picture of wiring]

Comment: Can you add a picture looking into the back of the wallbox?

Answer (score 2):

The group of 3 white wires is your neutral bundle.  Add the white wire from the new switch to it.

The group of two blacks is probably hot and a feed thru, connect both with the black from the switch.

Connect the remaining black (likely your load) to the blue wire.

Ground to ground.  And I bet you have it in the back of the box. (The house looks new enough)